# Count TCP retransmissions and find structure for storage of packets' information (C)

Tags: c, struct, tcp

I'm building a C program which sniffs packets in a specified interface using libpcap, and counts the TCP retransmissions per second.

To store packet information and further count the retransmissions ocurrences, I would need a dictionary-like structure, resembling the following one, where I would save the source, destination and sequence number of a packet (or its hash) as a key and the number of the sequence number ocurrences as a value:

**Source**: 192.168.1.2

**Destination**: 192.168.2.2

**Sequence_number**: 123456789

**Ocurrences**: 2

- the key could be a tuple:

  `{ (src_ip, dst_ip, seq_number) : #ocurrences }`

  `{ (192.168.1.2, 192.168.2.2, 123456789) : 2 }`
- or an hash (md5, for instance) to identify the packet uniquely:

  `{ hash_of_src_dst_seqnum : #ocurrences }`

  `{ 31078EB0CC34525058847E0BC632B23A : 2 }`

For this dictionary part, I know I can create a key_value struct, like so:

```
struct key_value
{
   int key;
   char* value;
};
```

The problem here is, I should only store information on 10.000 packets. When the structure is full, the oldest information inserted must be removed (like a FIFO)

My question is: considering this is a C program, what would be the most suited structure (also in terms of performance) for the storage of multiple (but limited) dictionaries? A linked list, a FIFO, a circular buffer? And what would be the code for that same structure, so that it will accept the dictionary as its items?

**NOTE:** the structure should look somehow like:

```
[ { 31078EB0CC34525058847E0BC632B23A : 2 }, { 31078EB0CC34525058847E0222232B23A : 1 }, ....]
```

Comment: *or an hash (md5, for instance) to identify the packet uniquely* Don't use a hash. `(src_ip, dst_ip, seq_number)` already identifies a packet (almost - pedantically, you need port data too, but leaving out port data **probably** will work anyway), and it doesn't require any computation, which can be expensive for hashes.  Just use a `struct key { inet_addr_t srcIP, inet_addr_t destIP, uint32_t seq, in_port_t srcPort, in_port_t destPort }` to identify a packet.  It's likely faster to compare that a bunch of times than compute a hash over the entire packet.

Comment: (cont) Look at your traffic statistics - compare the most unique first, whether that's sequence number, or source port, or source IP.  Once that's different, it can't be a retransmitted packet.